# Recognize pointer down event without delay in Flutter (iOS, Android)

Tags: user-interface, flutter, gesture, gesture-recognition

T'd like to track pointer events in Flutter (pointer down/up and pointer position) but there's always a delay (about 500ms) between the moment a finger touch the screen and the PointerDown event, unless I move my finger immediately.

The standard GestureDetector doesn't handle that (there is a delay to recognize TapDown event), so I tried the code below but to no avail: the delay is still there.

Any idea how could I solve this problem?

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';

typedef PositionEventHandler = void Function(Offset);

class MySimplePointerGestureRecognizer extends OneSequenceGestureRecognizer {
  final PositionEventHandler onPointerDown;
  final PositionEventHandler onPointerUpdate;
  final PositionEventHandler onPointerUp;

  MySimplePointerGestureRecognizer(
      {@required this.onPointerUp,
      @required this.onPointerUpdate,
      @required this.onPointerDown});

  @override
  void addPointer(PointerEvent event) {
    startTrackingPointer(event.pointer);
    resolve(GestureDisposition.accepted);
  }

  @override
  void handleEvent(PointerEvent event) {
    if(event is PointerDownEvent) {
      onPointerDown(event.position);
    }
    if (event is PointerMoveEvent) {
      onPointerUpdate(event.position);
    }
    if (event is PointerUpEvent) {
      onPointerUp(event.position);
      stopTrackingPointer(event.pointer);
    }
  }

  @override
  void didStopTrackingLastPointer(int pointer) {}

  @override
  String get debugDescription => 'simplePointerTracker';
}
```

Comment: use `Listener` widget for example

Comment: Listener works perfectly, I've no more a delay.
Thank you very much!